# Displaying a dictionary value from django model in a html

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a django model that consists of a `JSONField()`.
What I am trying to do is pass the details of this field to html, by the form of a context variable. The `JSONField()` stores a dictionary. For some reason the I only the first part of each dictionary element shows up in the presented html file.

**Models.py:**

```
class WholeValues(models.Model):
    eb_top_items_list = models.JSONField()
```

**Main.py**

```
#updating JSONField() values with a dictionary
eb_numbers_for_upload = WholeValues.objects.all()
eb_numbers_for_upload.update(eb_top_items_list=df_eb_values.head(n=6).to_dict())
```

**html**

```
<ul>
    {% for item in eb_top_items %}
    <ul> {{ item }}</ul>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

So the dictionary that is in my `.JSONField()` looks as follows

```
 {'ElectricBikeA': 13, 'ElectricBikeB': 12, 'ElectricBikeC': 11, 'ElectricBikeD': 11, 'ElectricBikeE': 7}
```

However displayed on the page is only the text part of the dictionary. what is displayed is missing the number values. All it has is ElectricBikeA, ElectricBikeB....etc

So i guess the real question is how can I get a context variable to show the values of the dictionary as well as the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) to loop through the keys and values of the dict as pairs

```
<ul>
    {% for key, value in eb_top_items.items %}
    <ul>{{ key }}: {{ value }}</ul>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```